# Is there a way to update the emoji font?

Tags: macos, keyboard, font, emoji

As you probably know,  and Unicode keeps adding new emojis, but, if like me, you can't or you don't want to update to the latest version of macOS, you don't have those emojis. I know that there are several emojis fonts such as

- [EmojiOne](http://emojione.com)
- [Twitter Emoji (Twemoji)](http://twitter.github.io/twemoji/)

But, I don't want to have this kind of library, I would like to have the "real" emojis from  (Yes, I ❤️ to use the Apple logo and emojis ).

Is there a way to update the emoji list from the  emojis?

This is my question, I think it's technically possible, but I have no idea where to find those emojis and how to update them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The font file you need to use a more recent version of is `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc` and is about 135MB.

The High Sierra version of the file and the process to install it to `/Library/Fonts` can be found here:
http://stephenradford.me/install-high-sierra-emoji-on-older-versions/

Note that the Emoji & Symbol picker will not list the newer emoji added since your version of macOS. For that to work you would also need to update at least  `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework` and maybe some other files.

Comment: Here is how to add emojis to the emoji picker on Mavericks: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/updating-maverickss-emoji-picker.2260530/ They're controlled by a plist in `CharacterPalette.app`.

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to restart for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either obtain a copy of the newer Apple Color Emoji font from a newer OS version and install it in your machine, or manually edit the one you have using a font editor app which can handle this kind of font.  I think the second option is not very practical for most users in terms of the work and skills required.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on El Capitan, it's quite easy. You need to temporarily disable SIP and copy the TTC file over to `/System/Library/Fonts`. You should turn SIP back on after you copy the font, since that imposes a security risk, since any app can have unlimited access to the `/System` folder once you grant it access to file system.

Yosemite and earlier are the easiest. All you need to do is copy the file to `/Library/Fonts`, and maybe reboot for the changes to fully take effect.

Catalina is slightly different. Once you disable SIP, you need to remount the `/System` partition as Read/Write (again, another security risk) by typing `sudo mount -uw /` into the Terminal. Copy it to `/System/Library/Fonts`

With Big Sur, you can't replace the font. However, it's still possible to update the font. Simply install the font, and disable the preinstalled font through Font Book.

**Make a back up of the original font!**

Comment: You used to be able to just copy it to the user-editable `/Library/` folder, or even just install it in font book. Did something change in recent releases where it has to be in `/System/`?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I realized I had made a mistake. In Yosemite, it is still inside `/Library/Fonts`, however since El Capitan and SIP, it was moved to `/System/`.

Correct me if I'm still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to avoid the SIP nonsense, even beyond Yosemite. Just copy the new version of Apple Color Emoji to ~/Library/Fonts.

I have tried this on Catalina, and upon opening Font Book, you can see multiple copies installed:

[image: fontbook conflict]

Then you can resolve by choosing the new version.

[image: fontbook resolve screen]

Comment: Can I ask where you got the updated version of the font file? The link in the accepted answer is long dead.

Comment: site:reddit.com "apple color emoji.ttc"

Comment: For me, going this route (adding the newer font file to Font Book and resolving the duplicate) resulted in strange behavior when using the emoji picker and viewing certain emoji.