# Is it possible to update macOS's emoji keyboard (to use all emojis)

Tags: keyboard, macos, ui, emoji

Following [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278937/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-emoji-font), I have obtained and installed macOS Mojave's `Apple Color Emoji.ttc` on macOS Sierra. While I can now see these emojis if I'm texted them, they don't show up on my emoji keyboard (even when placed in `/System/Library/Fonts/`)

One of the answers to that question mentioned that this would happen:

> Emoji & Symbol picker will not list the newer emoji added since your version of macOS. For that to work you would also need to update at least `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework` and maybe some other files.

Because of this, I tried switching out macOS Sierra's `CoreEmoji.framework` for Mojave's. This did not go well to say the least.

As soon as I renamed the original `CoreEmoji.framework` (to make sure that it still existed), Finder immediately froze, and when force quit didn't re-open, open applications stopped working, and I was unable to launch any apps or files. I was also unable to Log out, Restart, or Shutdown (except when pressing and holding the power button).

After shutting down, when attempting to restart, there was no restart sound, the progress bar didn't display any progress, after about 1 min the screen brightness was lowered a bit (like what happens when you computer is about to go to sleep or start a screensaver), and after 2-3 mins of starting up, the screen turned off completely. The computer didn't respond to any key presses or mouse activity.

I was able to undo the damage done by booting into the Recovery partition and using `mv` to move the origonal `CoreEmoji.framework` back into place, and was then able to restart into my regular macOS partition.

So, it turns out that changing something (that I wouldn't think make a big difference) like `CoreEmoji.framework` can make it so that macOS can't restart, so I was wondering if there is any way, other than by completely replacing `CoreEmoji.framework`, to get macOS Mojave's emojis to show up in the emoji keyboard. Does something like [EmojiAttributes](https://github.com/PoomSmart/EmojiAttributes) exist for macOS? Or, as ridiculous as this sounds, could [EmojiAttributes](https://github.com/PoomSmart/EmojiAttributes) be modified to work as a `mySIMBL` extension? The only problem with that solution is that I have no idea how to build with `theos`, as for some reason it seems that I didn't install it correctly on macOS or iOS (I followed the instructions for both, but it doesn't work).

Also, before you tell me that I did something less than optimally smart, yes, I do have backups of everything, and in the worst-case-scenario, could have reinstalled macOS.

Comment: When you say "emoji keyboard", do you mean Character Viewer (Edit > Emoji and Symbols), the expanded version?

Comment: @TomGewecke yes

Answer (score 3):

I haven't figured out how to make new emojis to appear in the main picker panel, but I've at least gotten them to be *searchable* from the picker in Mojave (10.14.6) as well as showing up in the frequently-used section. Here's the process I used to get Emoji 13.1 emojis from Monterey (12.0.1) to render and to be searchable from the Mojave picker.

Replacing the entire `CoreEmoji.framework` bundle ***DOES NOT WORK*** and will prevent you from booting successfully (as noted above). The Monterey version of the bundle is missing several files that Mojave seems to depend on, thus the bundles must be "merged", only files that exist in both bundle versions should be replaced.

As noted in the original post, modifying system files while booted is dangerous and probably won't work– boot to recovery mode and use terminal to replace files.

I'm not positive this works on other versions of macOS, but since **Monterey → Mojave** works, I'd assume **Big Sur/Catalina → Mojave** should work, and **Monterey → Big Sur/Catalina** should also work. As always, modifying core system files should be done at your own risk...

**Directions:**

1. Save backups of Mojave files:

   - Font: `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc`
   - Framework bundle: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/`
2. Acquire Monterey versions of the above resource files
3. Replace the following Mojave files with the Monterey versions:

   ***Don't replace the entire CoreEmoji.framework bundle, only replace files explicitly listed! Same goes for the `en.lproj` directory, don't replace the whole folder, just the three files listed below.***

   - `/System/Library/Fonts/`

     - `Apple Color Emoji.ttc`
   - `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`

     - `CharacterPicker-en.dat`
     - `emoji.bitmap`
     - `emoji.dat`
     - `emojimeta.dat`
     - `Emoticons.dat`
     - `equivalences.plist`
     - `FindReplace-en.dat`
     - `en.lproj/`

       - `AppleName.strings`
       - `TextToSpeech.stringsdict`
       - `Voiceover.strings`

[image: macOS Mojave emoji picker displaying post-release emojis in the frequently-used section]

[image: macOS Mojave emoji picker displaying post-release emoji in the search panel]

Comment: Because you are not actually answering the question posted, it would be more appropriate if you have created a new post with the appropriate question for this subject and answer it yourself after you have gained enough reputation (which is not high at all). See this [Help Center support page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) about how this is done.

Comment: On the contrary @Alper, I think this is the most appropriate place for the answer as people might want alternative solutions to the question, especially seeing that it is two years later and theoretically the question would still be unanswered. StackExchange is a place for finding solutions, and if search engines direct the user to this page for a possible solution to their query, then great! The remark about their reputation being "not high at all" is unnecessary; everyone is welcome.

Comment: @ckhatton. alper's remark re high rep is to state the level of rep needed to comment is not high (50), it's not a comment on the answerer's rep.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths, fair enough, as the whole comment came across as "having a stab" I initially thought they were ridiculing their reputation score - text messages tend to mislead their tone.