# Can I update my emoji set without updating my operating system?

Tags: messages, emoji, unicode

I'm on OS 10.12, and because of some legacy software I'm running, I can't upgrade. I have access to most emoji, but some of the newer icons, like , display as blank (e.g. in Messages) or as a box with a code inside (e.g. in Firefox).

Can I update my emoji set without updating my operating system?

Comment: Why don't you run this software in a virtual machine, and update your OS? You might want to be on the latest security updates anyway.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278937/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-emoji-font?rq=1