# After updating the emoji font in an older macOS, is there a way to visually find and insert newer emoji that the system emoji picker doesn't support?

Tags: font, emoji

I just updated the emoji font on my macOS 10.14.6 system using the method detailed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316942/23045).

This seems to have worked great in that I can now view newer emojis that people send me, or that appear on web pages. However, the emoji picker in Mojave doesn't support these emoji, leaving me with no good way to type them, other than finding them in an existing document somewhere and using copy/paste.

Is there a way to update the emoji picker to include these new emoji? Or perhaps use an alternative emoji picker?

(I'm aware I could use text replacements in System Preferences / Keyboard / Text to type the emoji, but I strongly prefer to be able to find emoji visually, hence the specific wording in my question.)

Answer (score 1):

All Emoji should show up when you use the expanded version of the Character Viewer. If you don't see Emoji on the list at the left, click on the gear wheel and then Customize to add it. You may also need to add the Unicode category and go to the range where the new Emoji are located (probably 1f300-1f900).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the new emojis don't show up in the Mojave character viewer.

Comment: @GuyGizmo could you give a specific example or two?

Comment: Neither the disguised face or pinched fingers emoji show up, along with everything else that's new in Big Sur. Mojave probably has a list of the emoji it displays built into the OS somewhere.

Comment: @GuyGizmo. Add Unicode to the list on the left side, select that,  and go to number 1F90C and click on that spot and see if pinched fingers shows up.  Normally Character Viewer in the Unicode category should show anything contained in any font.

Comment: Yes, the pinched fingers are there at that spot. I suppose I could add the unsupported characters to my favorites palette for easier access. It's not ideal but it's certainly better than nothing.